# Django redirect - not a valid view function or pattern name error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm a newbie in Django and am trying to set up a simple contact form which redirects to a thank you page on successful submission. I'm having trouble getting it to redirect to the thanks page after submission and getting the below error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /contact/
Reverse for 'thanks' not found. 'thanks' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

This is my `urls.py`

```
app_name = 'home'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view()),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.ContactView, name='contact'),
    url(r'^thanks/$', views.ThanksView, name='thanks'),
]
```

and my `views.py`

```
def ContactView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('thanks')
    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})

def ThanksView(request):
    return render(request, 'thanks.html', {})
```

I added the templates directory in my `settings.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/home', 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                # Third Party Apps
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',  # <--
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect', # <--
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Can someone please point out where I'm making a mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this should work

```
return redirect('home:thanks')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But I still get the same error even with `reverse('thanks')`. Interestingly, a redirect to another view name in a different app works even without the `reverse`. This makes me think that somehow, the view / url names in the `home` app seem to be not recognized..

Comment: @locke14 - apologies, it appears that the reverse isn't necessary (but I've always used it and it was all I could see that was wrong).

I have a new suggestion (if it works I'll edit the answer above) - since I see you've set an `app_name` to be `'home'`, try doing `return redirect('home:thanks')`

Comment: `return redirect('home:thanks')`works !! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that those names are defined in the respective `urls.py` files and the paths are referred to by their "names" there, which are generally different from the actual path names!

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps:

```
return redirect(reverse('appname:urlname'))
```

or with the kwargs, in case of 'urlname/':

```
return redirect(reverse('appname:urlname', kwargs={'kwarg':value}))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you define app_name for the name of app
you should write the url for your view like that

```html
<a href='{% url "name_of_app:name_of_view" %}'> Link </a>
```